# Verificar se existe um arquivo em determinada pasta rendered jsf

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee, jsf-2.2

Pessoal estou salvando imagem em uma determinada pasta do projeto e preciso verificar se esse arquivo existe na pasta. Estava usando um comando conforme abaixo:

```
rendered="Fotos/#{consultaFuncionariosBean.pessoaModel.codigo != null}.png"
```

Mas não funcionou. Alguém sabe como posso resolver isso?

Resolvido conforme Abaixo.

Metodo.

```
public boolean existeArquivo(String file) {
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    String nomeSaida = externalContext.getRealPath("") + "resources" + File.separator + "Fotos" + File.separator + file + ".png";
    File Arqs = new File(nomeSaida);
    boolean success = Arqs.exists();
    return success;
}
```

Form.

```
    <p:graphicImage rendered="#{photoCamBean.existeArquivo(consultaFuncionariosBean.pessoaModel.codigo)==false}" library="Fotos" name="Modelo.jpg" cache="false"/>
    <p:graphicImage rendered="#{photoCamBean.existeArquivo(consultaFuncionariosBean.pessoaModel.codigo)==true}" name="Fotos/#{consultaFuncionariosBean.pessoaModel.codigo}.png" cache="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O atributo `rendered` é Booleano.

---

Faça algo do tipo:

```
@ManagedBean
public class TesteMB {

    private File arquivo;
    private boolean arquivoExiste;

    public boolean getArquivoExiste() {
        return arquivo != null;
    }
}
```

E então:

```
rendered="#{testeMB.arquivoExiste}"
```

---

Ou para ficar mais fácil, pode fazer a verificação direto na view:

```
@ManagedBean
public class TesteMB {

    private File arquivo;

    public File getArquivo() {
        return arquivo;
    }
}
```

E então:

```
rendered="#{testeMB.arquivo != null}"
```

Comment: Obrigado Igor Resolvi conforme postado acima e de acordo com a sua ajuda grato.